# Prove by definition that the function is a plane continuity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Prove by definition that the function $f (x, y)$ is continuous in the set $M$ $(\delta = \delta (\varepsilon)-?)$

1. $ f (x, y) = 2x + 3y + 5,  M = R ^ 2$
2. $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2, M=(x,y \in R^2, x^2+y^2<4)$
3. $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, M=R^2$

By the epsilon-delta definition, $F(x,y)$ is continuous if for any positive epsilon, there is a positive delta such that for any point $(a,b)$, we have
$$d((x,y),(a,b))<\delta \Rightarrow d(F(x,y),F(a,b))<\epsilon.$$
By some manipulations with the norm, I figure that $|x−a|$ and $|y−b|$ both should be less than $\delta$, since the sum of their squares are less than the square of $\delta$.

Maybe I'm wrong, but wouldn't it already suffice to show that $$\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{y\to b}F(x,y)=F(a,b)?$$

Comment: I don't know how to do this please help

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: yes  sir  By the epsilon-delta definition, $F(x,y)$ is continuous if for any positive epsilon, there is a positive delta such that for any point $(a,b)$, we have $d((x,y), (a,b)) < \delta ==> d(F(x,y), F(a,b)) < \epsilon$

By some manipulations with the norm, I figure that $|x-a|$ and $|y-b|$ both should be less than $\delta$, since the sum of their squares are less than the square of $\delta$

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but wouldn't it already suffice to show that $lim_{x->a}lim_{y->b}F(x,y)=F(a,b)$